# eclipse not able to install CDT (c++ development tools) due to some dependences not satisfied

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I joined a new firm which has very restrict policy regarding using 3rd party software. There is a company certified Eclipse foundation IDE 4.16 installed on my Windows 10 (64 bits).

When I tried to install CDT (for C++ development) from Help-->Install New Software, I got following errors (sorry, I am not able to copy/paste, ).

"Cannot complete the install because soem dependencies are not satifiable
Software being installed: a.jre.javase 9.0.0
Software being intalled: C/C++ Development Tools 9.11.1.202006011430 (org.eclipse.cdt.feature.group 9.11.1.202006011430)
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: C/C++ Development Tools 9.11.1.202006011430 [org.eclipse.cdt.feature.group 9.11.1.202006011430]
To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu;org.eclipse.cdt.platform.feature.group [9.11.1.202006011430, 9.11.1.202006011430]
there are more, But I am tired of typing those error message.

How can I install p2 from Help --> Install New Software ? I tried to search p2, it gives a lot packages, when I tried to install all of them (as I don't know which one is exactly depended by CDT, I got another bunch of errors. Super frustrated !

Comment: This is an issue you need to take up with your company's IT department, not strangers on the Internet.

Comment: Unfortunately, my company's IT department probably isn't very helpful with such specific subject. The reason for me to seek help here is about how to install the p2 (from within Eclipse's "Help-> Install New Software".

Comment: You're asking us to help you circumvent their policy. You need to consult your company's resources to figure out what is available to you, not ask us what you can hack in.